# How to click on ok button of pop up message in jmeter recording

Tags: jmeter

I recorded using a proxy server and cannot see the pop up got recorded. My pop is a Confirm popup so I cannot use HTTP Authorization manager. I have to click on OK on this pop up to get to next page. What do I use for this kind of pop up?

Thank y

Comment: I'm afraid that's not supported by JMeter. What's the goal you want to accomplish? Maybe Selenium fits your use case?

Comment: JMeter recording doesn't care about UI. If popup was not recorded, it means it did not generate any HTTP traffic. Probably it's client-side only, or uses HTTPs or any other protocol. So you need to understand (using developer tools in browser) what popup does, and then see how it can be processed by JMeter.